# Rider: How to generate a OpenApi (Swagger) web service reference?

Tags: swagger, openapi, rider

With [Unchase.OpenApi](https://github.com/unchase/Unchase.OpenAPI.Connectedservice) exists a Visual Studio Extension to generate code for web services with [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag).

[image: Annimation]

This leads me to the following question: Is there a way to create a web service reference based on a swagger.json reference in Rider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the extension. Based on the gif I conclude, it generates clients one time and then the generated code is commited.
We use in our project another approach.

1. Add an OpenAPI reference to the csproj file

   ```
    <OpenApiReference Include="..\relative\path\to\openapi.json" CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp" ClassName="{controller}Client" Link="OpenAPIs\openapi.json" />
   ```
2. Reference the package NSwag.ApiDescription.Client
3. The client(s) will be generated before building the project and placed in obj directory. Since that they are available to use in your code.